# Node.js best way to add 'semi-dynamic' content

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, dynamic

I have database with users (username, password, games (array, storing only ids of games)). From separate module, I fetch data about games. On my webpage, user profile is templated with just **user** object. I want that info about games to be dynamic - user can add/delete those games dynamically, without reloading the page. Database integration is easy, I'd do this with AJAX, but should I send game data also through it? I haven't worked so far with Angular, but from what I heard, maybe its best way? Or maybe forget about templating, do everything with Angular?

Im using node.js, mangodb, express.

Comment: Node.js is a server-side JavaScript runtime. AngularJS is a client-side (browser) framework. (So they're essentially orthogonal.)  What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** "mix" `angular` with node template engines like `ejs` or `jade` based on `express` and have the main content rendered with the response and the rest of the content can be loaded or altered later using `ajax` and a `REST` API interface.

You well gain good performance as well as good SEO optimization since the "static" content is already on the page when it returns from the server

**In your case**

I'm suggestion you have a node express server with a few endpoints

- `[GET] /user/:id` - will render a static html page with the user details
- `[GET] /user/games` - will give a JSON response with the user games and added to the view using angular